# Java Applet Freezes IE8 under Windows XP and JRE 1.6.0_35

Tags: internet-explorer, applet, windows-xp, java

i am having a Problem,

When i am trieing to access an applet, which i deployed on the website, with the IE8 under XP, the IE freezes and crashes. This happens with the JRE Version 1.6.0_35

With the JRE version 1.6.0_24 the IE8 does Work without any problems and does not cause any freeze or crash.

The Applet itself has the following code in the html

```
<OBJECT
   type="application/x-java-applet"
   id="jsap"
   name="jsap"
   code="main"
   archive="applet.jar"
   width="1" height="1">
</OBJECT>
```

The width and height are set to 1, because it is an applet which should run in the background. The applet itself is done, to controll Downloads and acces the filesystem of the user. So it does have a JFileChooser. I guess there is a problem with the security of the Applet.The applet itself is signed. The java console does not even load, when i am on the site.

The following Error is generated by the IE8, but sadly i don´t understand anything of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="iexplore.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="ExtExport.exe" SIZE="144384" CHECKSUM="0xE4CFFC5E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer ImpExp FF exporter" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="extexport.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="extexport" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2C47C" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:03" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:03" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="hmmapi.dll" SIZE="68608" CHECKSUM="0x3639B01C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft HTTP Mail Simple MAPI" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="HMMAPI.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="HMMAPI" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1713E" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:24:27" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:24:27" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="iecompat.dll" SIZE="2048" CHECKSUM="0xBB531699" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer Compatibility Data" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="iecompat.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="iecompat" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xD321" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:02" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:02" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="iedvtool.dll" SIZE="743424" CHECKSUM="0x3A035A87" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer Developer Tools" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486 (longhorn_ie8_ldr.130403-1535)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="iedvtool.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="iedvtool.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xC3901" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:48" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:48" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="iedw.exe" SIZE="18432" CHECKSUM="0xF3AAB8D4" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="IE Crash Detection" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="iedw.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="iedw.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xD02C" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:34:47" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:34:47" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="ieproxy.dll" SIZE="247808" CHECKSUM="0x15CD5FED" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486" FILE_DESCRIPTION="IE ActiveX Interface Marshaling Library" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486 (longhorn_ie8_ldr.130403-1535)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ieproxy.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="ieproxy.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3DE8E" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:51" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="iexplore.exe" SIZE="638816" CHECKSUM="0x3532A3B9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="IEXPLORE.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="iexplore" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xA0294" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:06" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="jsdbgui.dll" SIZE="522240" CHECKSUM="0xEF96C0F7" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Script Debugger" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486 (longhorn_ie8_ldr.130403-1535)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="jsdbgui.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="jsdbgui.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x8449F" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:49" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="jsdebuggeride.dll" SIZE="121344" CHECKSUM="0xD614AFBB" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="JScript Debugger IDE" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="jsdebuggeride.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="jsdebuggeride.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x24B51" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:58" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="JSProfilerCore.dll" SIZE="118272" CHECKSUM="0x5A1D31D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="IE Dev Toolbar JScript Profiler" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="JSProfilerCore.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="JSProfilerCore.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x212B0" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:01" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="jsprofilerui.dll" SIZE="233984" CHECKSUM="0x8DCE4301" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Script Profiler" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="jsprofilerui.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="jsprofilerui.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x42482" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:05" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="pdm.dll" SIZE="355832" CHECKSUM="0xA49AB6D6" BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" PRODUCT_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Process Debug Manager" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008" FILE_VERSION="9.0.30729.1 built by: SP" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="pdm.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="pdm.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x663E0" LINKER_VERSION="0x90000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" LINK_DATE="07/29/2008 14:46:11" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/29/2008 14:46:11" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="sqmapi.dll" SIZE="134144" CHECKSUM="0x8299BD40" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" FILE_DESCRIPTION="SQM Client" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386 (vista_rtm.061101-2205)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="sqmapi.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="sqmapi" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x24A81" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" LINK_DATE="11/02/2006 09:44:16" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/02/2006 09:44:16" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="xpshims.dll" SIZE="12800" CHECKSUM="0x8AE3F054" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer Compatibility Shims for XP" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.23486 (longhorn_ie8_ldr.130403-1535)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="xpshims.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="xpshims.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x6D0E" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.23486" LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/16/2013 22:16:49" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwconn.dll" SIZE="61440" CHECKSUM="0xDEEFFF2A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwconn.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwconn" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x13C74" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:47" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:47" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwconn1.exe" SIZE="218624" CHECKSUM="0xD4E73FB1" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Assistent für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwconn1.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="icwconn1" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x42381" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:35" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:35" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwconn2.exe" SIZE="86016" CHECKSUM="0x79738D08" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Assistent für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ICWCONN2.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="ICWCONN2" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x24D5E" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:39" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:39" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwdl.dll" SIZE="32768" CHECKSUM="0xC40FE1DA" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internetdienst MIME Multipart Download" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ICWDL.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="ICWDL" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xDAE3" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:49" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwhelp.dll" SIZE="172032" CHECKSUM="0x86CA0A69" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Hilfsfunktionen für den Assistenten für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwhelp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwhelp" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2D858" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:50" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:50" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwres.dll" SIZE="65536" CHECKSUM="0x47F8A8C3" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Assistent für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwres.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwres" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x112BE" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 11:51:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 11:51:51" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwrmind.exe" SIZE="24576" CHECKSUM="0x5AFA2E44" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard Reminder" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ICWRMIND.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="ICWRMIND" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x15B6D" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:25" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwtutor.exe" SIZE="73728" CHECKSUM="0x5509E6A1" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Assistent für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwtutor.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="icwtutor" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x14A6D" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:49:08" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:49:08" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwutil.dll" SIZE="49152" CHECKSUM="0xFF06931E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Assistent für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwutil.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwutil" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x14509" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:52" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 02:20:52" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\inetwiz.exe" SIZE="20480" CHECKSUM="0x8F39C3D9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Assistent für den Internetzugang" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="INETWIZ.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="INETWIZ" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x10EAC" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:41" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:41" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\isignup.exe" SIZE="16384" CHECKSUM="0xCF0DBE89" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Signup" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ISIGNUP.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="ISIGNUP" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xF492" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:48:46" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:48:46" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\trialoc.dll" SIZE="40960" CHECKSUM="0x68DD9EA8" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard Trial Reminder Helper" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="trialoc.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="trialoc" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xE8A6" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 11:52:35" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 11:52:35" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
<MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="1063936" CHECKSUM="0xE83A657" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Client-DLL für Windows NT-Basis-API" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.121001-1622)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1044D0" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6293" LINK_DATE="10/03/2012 04:58:00" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/03/2012 04:58:00" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

Thanks in advance for reading this

Comment: IE8 log can be read by aliens only.